# Cannot read private member from an object whose class did not declare it...?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror, private-members, class-fields

In this program:

```js
class Example {

  #privateMember = 123;

  // these are fine  
  addNumber (n) { return this.#privateMember + n; }
  doAddNumber (n) { return this.addNumber(n); }

  // "cannot read private member #privateMember from an 
  // object whose class did not declare it"
  #operations = { add: this.addNumber };
  operate (n) { return this.#operations.add(n); }

}

const ex = new Example();
console.log(ex.addNumber(77));
console.log(ex.doAddNumber(77));
console.log(ex.operate(77));
```

Calling `addNumber` works fine, so does `doAddNumber`, but calling `operate` yields the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read private member #privateMember from an object whose class did not declare it
    at Object.addNumber [as add] (<anonymous>:11:17)
    at Example.operate (<anonymous>:20:29)
    at <anonymous>:27:16
    at dn (<anonymous>:16:5449)
```

I can't make any sense of this error because:

1. `addNumber` works fine, so its not a syntax error or a typo at least.
2. `doAddNumber` works fine, so its not a problem calling functions from other functions.
3. `operate` just calls `addNumber` which, from (1), works fine.
4. `this` *is* an object whose class declares `#privateMember`... I mean, `this` is an `Example` and I can see that it's declared in `Example`. It's right there... I typed it myself...

I found [TypeError: Cannot read private member from an object whose class did not declare it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72805454/typeerror-cannot-read-private-member-from-an-object-whose-class-did-not-declare) but I can't understand how it applies, if it applies.

I can't figure out what's going on here. Why doesn't `operate` work even though `addNumber` and `doAddNumber` do?

In my real code (this is just a minimal example), I am trying to use a dictionary like `#operations` to hold implementations of a number of various algorithms for performing a task, indexed by a string ID, where the string algorithm ID is specified to the constructor. This is also convenient because I can get the keys from this dictionary to provide a list of valid algorithm IDs without having to duplicate that list anywhere. Now, I can just switch it to an `if` statement and make sure I keep the queryable list up to date as well, but I can't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: "*`this` is an object whose class declares `#privateMember`*" - no it's not. Check in your debugger what `this` really is. It may be the expected instance of `Example` in `ex.addNumber(…)`, but it's not in `#operations.add(…)`.

Comment: Btw it seems like your `#operations` field should be a `static` member.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the hint! As for it being static; I guess I could do that; if I move the required (see answers) `call`/`bind` into the method that invokes it, then I don't need to reference `this` in the `#operations` declaration. I wanted it to be static when I wrote it, since it's philosophically more appropriate and also I wouldn't need to create a temporary `new Example()` to get the list of keys from `#operations`, but couldn't figure out a way to make that happen. It's hard to get used to JS coming from C++, heh.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, but in my real code, the equivalent of `addNumber` is actually private (starts with `#`); that didn't make it into this example snippet because it didn't affect the problem I was asking about here. Turns out (from [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)) that "Unlike public methods, private methods are not accessible on Class.prototype". So I can't do `Example.prototype.#privateMethod`, unfortunately. Ah well. But I agree, it *should* be static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set `#operations.addNumber` and then call it, `this === #operations`, not `ex`, which fails because `ex.#operarions.#privateMember` does not exist.

If I change your `Example` class with

```
#operations = { add: this.addNumber.bind(this)};
```

then `ex.#operations.add` runs with `this === ex` and your code returns

```
> 200
> 200
> 200
```

Comment: Confirmed, logging `this` from within `addNumber` indeed shows the contents of `#operations`. How about that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of what I believe you're after...

```js
class Example {

  #privateMember = 123;

  // these are fine  
  addNumber (n) { return this.#privateMember + n; }
  doAddNumber (n) { return this.addNumber(n); }

  // "cannot read private member #privateMember from an 
  // object whose class did not declare it"
  #operations = { add: this.addNumber };
  operate (n) { return this.#operations.add.call(this, n); }

}

const ex = new Example();
console.log(ex.addNumber(77));
console.log(ex.doAddNumber(77));
console.log(ex.operate(77));
```

In short, in your code the #operations method is simply creating an object with a reference to the Example class method of addNumber, with no association to any object.  So, when attempting to make use of this reference, you need to pass an object...

Ie, you're essentially defining...

```
#operations = { add: Example.prototype.addNumber }
```

In the proposed solution, the `operate` method invokes the reference to the `addNumber` method in the #operations object, but of course has to pass an object to `addNumber`, and does so by performing a `call( this, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks! I marked the other answer as correct because I was able to confirm that `this` in `addNumber` actually *is* the `#operations` object when invoked via `.add` (as opposed to `Example.prototype`), and it was clear on that point. But I really appreciate the suggested solution code you wrote. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries.  I was simply trying to draw out the distinction between an object method reference and invoking an object method reference.  @JSmart523's solution is certainly cleaner...